# Interfacing Bosch BNO055 with nrf52840 using segger IDE

Tags: c, embedded, nrf52

Can anyone help me with the reading the data register values from BNO055 sensor with nrf52840 microcontroller using i2c communication protocol.

i have initiated the MCU master twi and also initiated the Sensor and it is acknowledging but i am not able to read the outputs of the registers , even after write/read to the registers of the sensors, i am not able to read the output.

if anyone have idea on interfacing BME680 with the nrf52 series. kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.
Good day !!

Comment: Did you look at the datasheet? There is a section about the i2c interface: https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bme680-ds001.pdf

Comment: Yes, i have seen it. and i am able to succesfully run the code with write and read to the registers in it. but im not able to print the outputs in Embedded segger studio IDE.any idea on nrf52840 communication with bme680 ?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Have you worked on it?

Comment: I have never worked with SEGGER Studio. You might want to add your sourcecode to the question so we can help you. Your description suggests that your only problem is to log your data and make it visible in your IDE

Comment: @M.Kotzjan Correct. that is the only problem. Can you tell me how to attach the source code here?

Comment: You can edit your question and paste the code into it. It might be better to open a new question about log output in SEGGER Studio though

Comment: How SO works:  You show your code, we help you fix it.  We could tell you how to do it from niothing, but we-d be telling you no more than was in the data sheet.  There are three parts to this 1) working I2C code.  2) accessing the I2C device correctly, 3) working hardware.  You have failed in one or more of those prerequisits - what more can we say.

Comment: Thanks, guys,we achieved the sensor integration and development